# Google Calendar API Watch Events - Can't get sync message or push notifications?

Tags: python, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I'm able to implement the watch, as my logs indicate that I'm receiving the correct response. The domain I'm using has also been verified.

However, I noticed that I didn't receive the sync message or any push notifications when I make changes on the calendar I'm watching. I checked out my App Engine dashboard and it looks like I'm getting a client side 401 error. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check the [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) documentation on regarding how to make watch requests. If you are receiving a [401 error](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials) : Invalid Credentials, try the suggested actions in the page like get a new access token, review OAuth flow, or try using service account.

Comment: Lastly, see [Creating a Notification for Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) on how to build handheld notifications that are also sent to wearables. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you successfully registered your web hook for notifications you should receive sync message first. Did you have such request on your side?